# AWS CodeDeploy with Lambda Layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-codepipeline, aws-sam

I have a template.yaml function where I am defining a simple lambda function and a simple lambda layer.

I am able to deploy it properly using sam build, sam package and sam deploy and it works just fine. But I am trying to deploy using CodePipeline (Source -> Build -> Prod).
The prod stage works when I don't add the lambda layer definition. It does not work when I add it.

The issue is the lambda layer references `.aws-sam` directory which is only created after I would do a `sam build`. I am unsure how to reference the function to create a lambda layer. I saw that CodeBuild outputs a packaged.yaml file in s3 but this is the code URIs:

Func1: `CodeUri: s3://{}/{hash}`

but the layer uri is not changing to point to the correct uri: `ContentUri: ./.aws-sam/build/ImageProcessingLib`

Here is the `template.yaml` definition that works without CodePipeline.

```
  ImageProcessingLib:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src/layers/imageProcessingLib/
      Handler: image_processing_lib.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7


  ImageProcessingLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      Description: Lambda layer for writing additional functions for indexing and searching images
      LayerName: ImageProcessingLib
      ContentUri: ./.aws-sam/build/ImageProcessingLib
      CompatibleRuntimes: 
        - python3.7
      RetentionPolicy: Delete
    DependsOn: ImageProcessingLib
```

Is the fix as simple as changing the `CodeUri` of `ImageProcessingLayer`?